# Is the definition of array dimension in c++ primer different from others?

Tags: c++, arrays

In the `Array` chapter (p.113, 5th edition) of *C++ Primer*, it states:

> An array declarator has the form `a[d]`, where `a` is the name being defined and `d` is the dimension of the array. The dimension specifies the number of elements and must be greater than zero.

An later example from the chapter:

> ```
> int a2[] = {0, 1, 2};  // an array of dimension 3
> ```

As [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376218/what-do-we-mean-by-dimension-when-talking-about-arrays) said, it is a one-dimensional array for sure. But why Lippman said differently? Is there any misunderstanding in my mind?

Comment: Is this question about the compiler inferring the number of elements from the initializer?

Comment: @user4581301 I think it's just about the wording.

Comment: The book usage of the term ["dimension"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dimension) is correct, but not very common in this context. On the other hand, the more common usages of the term "dimension" is actually flawed, as C++ doesn't have multiple-dimension array. For example, what is commonly called a "2d" array (as in `char twod[X][Y]`) is actually not truly two-dimensional at all, but rather a one dimensional array where each element is in turn a one dimensional array. It's more an *emulation* of multiple dimensions.

Comment: `int a2[] = {0, 1, 2};` has the same net effect as `int a2[3] = {0, 1, 2};`.     The only difference is that, in the first, the compiler works out the number of elements in the array from the initialiser (`{0,1,2}`).   In both cases, `a2` has `3` elements.   Some people refer to that as "dimension" but that word is a bit overloaded (can have different meanings) in this context.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - To a mathematician, the distinction you make is moot.   An n-dimensional vector (synonymous with a matrix or array) for n > 0 is an vector of (n-1)-dimensional vectors.  (Where a zero-dimensional matrix is a scalar).  It is an abstract representation of multiple dimensions - the concrete realisations of that are all treated the same way.   It is only computer scientists (more specifically, computer scientists who use one or more of a number of specific programming languages) who make a distinction between a two-dimensional array and an array of one-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dimension == Length in this case

Answer (score -1):

From what I believe is a global understanding, dimensions can be defined as number of subscripts required to point to an individual element of array. Even the first definition at the top is wrong,

> Blockquote
> An array declarator has the form a[d], where a is the name being defined and **d is the dimension of the array**. The dimension specifies the number of elements and must be greater than zero.
> Blockquote

d is the length of the array and not dimension. and as you have corrected pointed out the given example also is a 1-D array.

Edit: As others have pointed out, it might just be the way author is defining things in his book, so its more about the wordings here. Anyways keep your concepts clear (seems like you already have grasped it) because the definitions going to be different in other books.

Comment: No, there's no "correct" or "wrong" here. There's use of an overloaded term, and the author is explicit in what meaning he uses in *his book*.